# Python 3 How do I temporarily disable tracing variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python 3.4.1 on windows, if that should help.

**Q1: How do I temporarily disable tracing variables**
I have a variable field with at trace, and I would like to temporarily disable the trace so that I can change the value of the field without triggering the call to the trace function.

Does it make sense?

And it might be that I am doing it all wrong (and I join a snippet of code):

I have a drop down list that shows a list of items I can choose from.
I have a second drop down list that shows, for each of the items in the first drop down menu, a list of "sub items", which of course must be updated when I change the first drop down menu.

**Q2: The question is, how do I "repack" the second drop down menu when the first one is changed?**

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

WORKINGWINDOWWIDTH  = 800                         # Width for the working window
WORKINGWINDOWHEIGHT = 800                         # Height for the working window

root = tk.Tk()

w = tk.Canvas(root, width=WORKINGWINDOWWIDTH - 10, height=WORKINGWINDOWHEIGHT - 10, bg="darkred")

def display_parameters(*args):
    print("args: {0}, and I have the following option: {1}".format(args, functionChoiceVar.get()))
    if functionChoiceVar.get() == "Option 1":
        print("I picked the first one...")
        print("How do I repack the presets?")
    elif functionChoiceVar.get() == "Option 2":
        print("I picked the second one...")
    return

def display_options(*args):
    print("args: {0}, and I have the following suboption: {1}".format(args, presetChoiceVar.get()))
    return

functionChoiceVar = tk.StringVar(root)
functionChoices   = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
functionOption    = tk.OptionMenu(root, functionChoiceVar, *functionChoices)
functionOption.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)
functionOption.place(x= 10, y=10)
functionChoiceVar.set('Option 1')
functionChoiceVar.trace("w", display_parameters)

presetChoiceVar   = tk.StringVar(root)
presetChoices11   = ['Suboption 11', 'Suboption 12', 'Suboption 13', 'Suboption 14','Suboption 15']
presetChoices12   = ['Suboption 21', 'Suboption 22', 'Suboption 23', 'Suboption 24','Suboption 25']
presetOption      = tk.OptionMenu(root, presetChoiceVar, *presetChoices11)
presetOption.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=10)
presetOption.place(x= 100, y=10)
presetChoiceVar.set('Suboption 11')
presetChoiceVar.trace("w", display_options)
```

Comment: Could you please move that second question to another question? Every question should ask one thing.

Answer (score 6):

When you set a trace, tkinter will return an id which you can use to later remove the trace with the `.trace_vdelete()` method. To restart the trace, simply do what you did the first time.

An easy way to keep track of the trace id is to store it as an attribute right to the instance of a `StringVar`.

For example:

```
functionChoiceVar.trace_id = functionChoiceVar.trace("w", display_parameters)
...
functionChoiceVar.trace_vdelete("w", functionChoiceVar.trace_id)
```

(by the way, unrelated to the question that was asked, calling `.pack()` and then immediately calling `.place()` serves no purpose. You can remove the call to `.pack()` because it gets negated by the call to `.place()` )

Comment: What about the case where you don't have access to the original callback function name from when the wrapper ID was created with the call to the .trace() method?  A call to .trace_vinfo() will give the ID once again, but is there a way to "decode" that wrapper ID into the originally-supplied callback function?

Comment: `trace_vdelete` has been superseded by `trace_remove`.

Comment: ...and `trace` by `trace_add`.

Answer (score 2):

### A1: how to remove tracing temporarily & return it afterwards

```
aWriteTracerID = presetChoiceVar.trace( "w", aWriteHANDLER )  # SAVE <<aTracer>> ID#
# setup code continues

presetChoiceVar.trace_vdelete(          "w", aWriteTracerID ) # REMOVE <<aTracer>>
# code
# that needs the write-tracer
# to have been removed
# ...

aWriteTracerID = presetChoiceVar.trace( "w", aWriteHANDLER )  # SET AGAIN
```

Comment: I am sorry that I did not thank you guys for your answers.

I thought that I would get a message from stackoverflow if there were answers, and I got too busy to check.

Thank you for the mention of trace_vdelete().

Although I learned a lot in the month since I posted, I had not yet stumbled upon it!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this myself while creating a new class which inherits from a base class taking a variable as an input keyword argument. So I developed the below routine which attempts to recover a named callback function from the globals() based on the fact that the Trace ID is nothing more than some numerical digits prepended to the original callback function name.  I expect that those digits have some meaning, but I was not able to ascertain them. Here's the routine:

```
def get_observer_callback(id):
    func = None
    funcname = id.lstrip('0123456789')
    if funcname != '<lambda>' and funcname in globals():
        func = globals().get(funcname)
        if type(func) is not type(lambda:()):
            func = None
    return func
```

While testing, a trace_id was **50360848my_callback** and the callback function was identified as

```
  <function my_callback at 0x03064370>
```

Interestingly, 50360848 from the wrapper is hex 0x03007210, which is in the same ballpark as hex 0x03064370 from the function description.  I couldn't find a hard relationship between the two beyond that...
I would describe the above routine as a kludge, but maybe, given the Tk implementation, the above kludge is sufficient for named functions.  Clearly it is not helpful for lambda functions.  I expect that within Tk there's a registration table which holds all the desired information, including references to the function objects.  Ideally a call which returns the function object from within the Tk internal table would be best.  Any input is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to remove a trace would be to say:

```
idx = 0  # This is the index of the first trace on tk_variable.
tk_variable.trace_remove(*tk_variable.trace_info()[idx])
```

To add the trace back, you can say:

```
tk_variable.trace_add('write', your_function)
```

To check if a variable is traced, you can say:

```
if tk_variable.trace_info():
    # do something
    pass
```